# How do I configure Web API .Net core to accept Binary JSON?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, bson

In Web API 2.1 I register BSON with the following:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Formatters.Add(new BsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to register the formatter .Net Core Web API.  It seems certain that it will be in the Startup.Configuration, but I'm still pretty new to Core and not sure how to add this type formatter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like in the startup.cs, the mvc config should look something like this.

```
using WebApiContrib.Core.Formatter.Bson;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc()
                .AddBsonSerializerFormatters();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This took me forever to find.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone using .NET Core and using the minimal services for Mvc with AddMvcCore(), AddBsonSerializerFormatters() doesn't show up. I checked the project on GitHub (github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib.Core). There is only an extension written for IMvcBuilder and none for IMvcCoreBuilder. As a workaround I wrote my own extension method. Hope it helps someone.

**BuilderExtensions.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System;
using WebApiContrib.Core.Formatter.Bson;

namespace ApiGateway.Extensions
{
    public static class BuilderExtensions
    {
        public static IMvcCoreBuilder AddBsonSerializerFormatters(this IMvcCoreBuilder builder)
        {
            if (builder == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
            }

            builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(
                ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>, MvcBsonSerializerOptionsSetup>());
            return builder;
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    // example usage 
    services.AddMvcCore()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddJsonFormatters().AddBsonSerializerFormatters()
            .AddApiExplorer();
    // ...
}
```